# SSL socket cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I have this script which i want to use to connect to a web service.

```
package pdslipay;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import za.co.ipay.retail.system.bizswitch.IpayMessageWrapper;
import za.co.ipay.retail.system.bizswitch.IpayMessageWrapper2;

public class ConnectionManager{

    private static ConnectionManager connectionManagerInstance = null;
    static Socket socket = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    public static SSLClientTest sslConnect = new SSLClientTest();

    private ConnectionManager() {

       }
    public static ConnectionManager getConnectionManagerInstance() {
          if(connectionManagerInstance == null) {
              connectionManagerInstance = new ConnectionManager();
          }
          return connectionManagerInstance;
       }

    /**
     * Waits on response from server
     *
     * @param socket Server socket
     */
     public String readServerResponse(Socket socket) {
            String results = null;
            try { 
                BufferedInputStream serverReader = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                IpayMessageWrapper2 wrap = new IpayMessageWrapper2();
                StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] all = wrap.unWrap(serverReader);
                for (int n = 0; n < all.length; n++) {
                    char c = (char) all[n];
                    build.append(c);
                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                results = build.toString();
                System.out.println("\n\nStringBuilder " + build.toString());
                //pay.responsePrepaid(build.toString());
                //pay.responsePostPay();
                return results;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: Unable to read server response\n\t" + ex);
            }
            return "ERROR";
        }

    public String connection(String build) {
        BufferedOutputStream buff = null;
        String results = "ERROR";

        try {

            char[] passw = "clientpw".toCharArray();
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream ( "resource/bizswitch-keys" ), passw );

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, passw);

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(ks);
            TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

            SSLContext sclx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sclx.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);

            SSLSocketFactory factory = sclx.getSocketFactory();
            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket( "01.000.000.198", 9102 );
            socket.startHandshake();


            IpayMessageWrapper wrap = new IpayMessageWrapper();

            buff = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            buff.write(wrap.wrap(build.getBytes()));
            buff.flush();

            System.out.println("Info: Message has been sent..." + build);
            // Wait for server response
            results = getConnectionManagerInstance().readServerResponse(socket);

            return results;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } 
        return results;
    }


}
```

On this line

`SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket( "01.000.000.198", 9102 );` i have an error

> SSLSocket cannot be resolved to a type

If i import sslsocket

```
package pdslipay;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import za.co.ipay.retail.system.bizswitch.IpayMessageWrapper;
import za.co.ipay.retail.system.bizswitch.IpayMessageWrapper2;
```

i get the error `Unhandled exception type NoSuchProviderException`

How can i correct the code so as to read my keystore and establish an secure ssl connection?.

Comment: Read the tutorial on exceptions. Either you can handle the excetion, and you should catch it. Or you can't, and you should declare it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 0):

The first error simply tells you to import that class.

After doing that, the compiler is able to tell you about other problems within your code, in this case about that exception that is not handled in your code.

You need to either add the exception to the throws list of your method or catch/process it. Very much like that IOException that your code already deals with!